# Finding Unique visitors to a webpage

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to write a pig script that find number of unique userid that visiots a particluar webpage.

table definition :`a = (userid:chararray, otherid:chararray, webpage:chararray)`

This is what I wrote but it doesn't work

```
a = (userid:chararray, otherid:chararray, webpage:chararray)
group_by_page = GROUP a by webpage ;
count_d = FOREACH group_by_page GENERATE group, count(distinct(a.userid));
```

Comment: How that is related to Java?

Comment: i think it isn't. I removed that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `DISTINCT` inside a nested foreach; it's not a UDF. This should get you where you need to go:

```
a = LOAD 'input' AS (userid:chararray, otherid:chararray, webpage:chararray);
group_by_page = GROUP a by webpage;
count_d = FOREACH group_by_page { uniq = DISTINCT a.userid; GENERATE group, COUNT(uniq); };
```

Go [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#foreach_nested) to learn more about nested foreach.

Comment: when running count_d = FOREACH group_by_page { uniq = DISTINCT a.userid; GENERATE group, count(uniq); }; throws following error......ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: I should have corrected your case -- the UDF is called `COUNT`, not `count`.